# Exclude Fields while saving document in mongodb in c#

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, database, nosql

Is there any way we can exclude fields while saving document in mongodb using c# ?
For example my class is

```
class student
{
int rollnol;
string name;
string fees;
}
```

What i want is that when i do collection.Save(studentobject) it should not save fees field.

(I am using this in asp.net MVC so anything using annotation could also work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the BsonIgnore attribute to ignore an element during serialization  http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.1/html/0b6cf485-682b-cbdf-25b4-b28401824c78.htm

```
class student
{
   int rollnol;
   string name;

   [BsonIgnore]
   string fees;
}
```